# Tricky Line Algorithm for a Game (language agnostic)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, line, collision-detection, trigonometry

I need help creating a specialized line-collision algorithm that allows "cutting corners" at certain angles.

In the following pictures, let the blue square represent the player and the black square represent a wall. The white squares, then, represent squares in a player's "line of sight" (valid squares), and the grey squares are squares outside a player's "line of sight" (invalid squares):

[image: img1]

The second image is where things get more interesting as we start cutting corners:

[image: img2]

Let's take a closer look at this line which is allowed despite passing over the corner of the wall:

[image: img3]

**The line is allowed because:**

- dx <= 0.5 (with a square being 1x1)
- dx/dy is above a certain ratio (say, 2 - I'm not sure of the exact value represented in these images.)

The converse line is not allowed because the ratio (of dy/dx in this case) is too low:

[image: img4]

**Or perhaps I should talk about the angle of entry vs exit from the square....**

The main problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to generalize a solution for vectors traveling at any angle between two points on the grid. I can't decide if I should use trigonometry or what. My closest solution so far has been to use the decimal parts of line interceptions with each square as the dx and dy's and check whether it's allowed based on the slope of the line and what quadrant it's in.

**Can anyone help?**

I've also looked at borrowing or starting from other line algorithms, but I haven't found anything too useful. Most of them that I've seen want a line from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) to be the same as from (x2, y2) to (x1, y1) which makes this problem quite different.

Comment: I am presuming you can have many walls, and they are not always adjacent to the player's position? Can you post your current algorithm (pseudocode at least)?

Comment: My first thought is to look at how close the line gets to the center of the square.  But in your second example, it doesn't make sense to me that this process isn't symmetric: I can see you, but you can't see me?

Comment: Exactly, Teepeemm: A line from point A to B isn't usually the same as from point B to A, when dx != dy != 0. I'll see if I can get a pseudocode example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the rules here. In your "cutting corners" image, the point `2 left, 1 down` is visible. The point `4 left, 2 down` is not. The slope for those two is the same, and it passes through the wall square in the same spot. So.... why?

Comment: Your requirement seems equivalent to A at `(xa,ya)` can hit B at `(xb,yb)` also when there is a line between `(xa,ya+1)` and `(xb,yb)` that does not touch an obstacle. This would provide the asymmetry as if A could raise his shooter above his head into the next block to strike B, but B's ability to do likewise to strike the portion of A above A's head is negligible.

Comment: Geobits - You're right. I wasn't thinking when I colored those cells in, they should be white as well as the slope is the same.

Comment: A. Webb - In the case of 2 over 1 up they are equivalent, but i don't think it's equivalent in general.

Comment: I do disagree with the claim that "line from point A to B is not usually the same as from point B to A". It's against anything we know about geometry :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using circles, they are quite optimal corner wise.

I assume that coordinates are taken at the center of each pixels.

The algorithm for knowing if (xo,yo) is hiding the view from (xa,ya) to (xb,yb) would then be:

- compute (xc,yc) the nearest point to (xo,yo) on the line from (xa,ya) to (xb,yb)
- compute distance d from (xo,yo) to (xc,yc)
- if d < half a pixel, then the view is hidden

You can simplify first two stages by directly calculating the distance between point and line http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line and eventually compute squared distance if you want to avoid sqrt

Comment: This allows cutting corners, but it doesn't account for the fact that (xa, ya) to (xb, yb) may be allowed, but (xb, yb) to (xa, ya) not allowed, that corners can only be cut if they enter below a certain angle.